# Formal proof with first order logic axioms.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, formal-proofs, natural-deduction

How do I formally prove the following:

$$[\forall y Gy \wedge \exists x Hx] \iff \exists x[\forall y Gy \wedge  Hx]$$

and by formally I mean using premises and whatever other first order logical axioms are needed.

I proved it like such, but this is not how I was supposed to do it.

$[\forall y Gy \wedge \exists x Hx] \iff \exists x[\forall y Gy \wedge  Hx]$        : Distribute Quantifier

$\implies$ $[\forall y Gy \wedge \exists x Hx] \iff [\forall x\forall y Gy \wedge \exists x Hx]$ :Null Quantification

$\implies$ $[\forall y Gy \wedge \exists x Hx] \iff [\forall y Gy \wedge \exists x Hx]$

Can anyone help? Here are some of the Axioms accepted:

$$M.P: Modus Ponens$$

$$TA : Tautologies$$

$$\forall x(\delta \implies  \psi) \implies (\forall x\delta \implies  \forall x\psi)$$

$$E.I: Existential Instantiation$$
$$U.G: Universal Generalization$$
$$U.I: Universal Instantiation$$
$$E.G: Existential Generalization$$

Comment: This depends on the axioms and rules you have available. Can you please post them?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I will edit it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your language includes the connective $\iff$. How should it be interpreted? Aren't there any propositional calculus rules?

Comment: @GitGud $\iff$ is included yes, I only listed some of the axioms.

Comment: @GitGud You could interpret it as $(p \implies q) \wedge (q \implies p)$

Comment: I don't have the time to type a proper answer. [Here](http://imgur.com/Yp4pIQr) is a partial proof omitting justifications.

Comment: @GitGud Just what I was looking for, but missing the justifications as you said. I'll leave this open so whenever you can type it up I'll mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: @GitGud just one more question, would it suffice to show that theres no need to prove the other direction ? since we can make a similar argument?

Comment: No. You're asked to prove $(\forall y Gy \wedge \exists x Hx) \leftrightarrow \exists x(\forall y Gy \wedge  Hx)$. You can do this by either somehow proving that a proof of this statement exists without explicitly providing a proof, or you can give an explicit formal proof. In a formal proof there's no leeway for things such as "the other direction" is similar. Plus, if you check the proof I've provided, even though there's some symmetry, it's not completely symmetric using these rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof that I think complies with your rules.

[image: Formal proof]

Answer (score 2):

I see you were trying Quantifier Distribution and null Quantification so I assume it is ok to  use equivalence rules.

Well, this is an immediate application of a Prenex Law:

$Q \land \exists x \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (Q \land \phi(x))$

Where Q does not contain $x$ as a free variable.

If equivalence rules are not allowed, then we will need to know what inference rules you are allowed.

Comment: Yes I know about the Prenex Law but I still don't know how to write it formally. Would it be something along the lines of: $$[1]: 1. [\forall y Gy \wedge \exists x Hx] : Premise$$
$$[1]: 2.\forall y [Gy \wedge \exists xHx] :Prenex $$

Comment: The Prenex Law is an equivalence principle ... I have never seen it as an inference rule. But, if it were an inference rule, it would go either way.